# Python make list of dicts from list of tuples

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, dictionary, tuples

from database I got result in format:

```
result = ([('A', 210L), ('B', 1L), ('C', 269L)], 3)
```

I need to change it in Python to:

```
[{'description':'A','sum':210},{'description':'B','sum':1},{'description':'C','sum':269}]
```

I tried various options but did not get what I needed..

```
rows = len(result[0])
description_sum = {}
all_descriptions_sums = []
for i in range(rows):
    description_sum['description'] = result[0][i][0]
    description_sum['sum'] = int(result[0][i][1])
    all_descriptions_sums.append(description_sum)
return all_descriptions_sums
```

It results in:

```
[{'description':'C','sum':269},{'description':'C','sum':269},{'description':'C','sum':269}]
```

So in the step `all_descriptions_sums.append(description_sum)` the dictionary is not just appended to the list, but it also rewrites the previous value..

Thank you so much for help!

Comment: `description_sum = {}` should be inside the `for` loop

Comment: Note that if it comes from a SQL database, most python database adapters have a way to retrieve rows as dicts instead of tuples (cf `DictCursor` for MySQL as an example).

Comment: thanks for suggestion, I ll explore that :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just use list comprehension:

```
result = [{'description': a, 'sum': int(b)} for a, b in result[0]]
```

But if you don't want to, what's wrong in your code, is that you initialize the dictionary before the loop. You have to redeclare it in each iteration, as in:

```
rows = len(result[0])
all_descriptions_sums = []
for i in range(rows):
    description_sum = {}
    description_sum['description'] = result[0][i][0]
    description_sum['sum'] = int(result[0][i][1])
    all_descriptions_sums.append(description_sum)
return all_descriptions_sums
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to move description_sum to the for loop.

```
all_descriptions_sums = []
for i in range(rows):
    description_sum = {}
    description_sum['description'] = result[0][i][0]
    description_sum['sum'] = int(result[0][i][1])
    all_descriptions_sums.append(description_sum)
```

And you can use list comprehension to make it clearer as other answer suggests.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will solve your issue:

```
# Input data
result = ([('A', 210L), ('B', 1L), ('C', 269L)], 3)
# Result list
list_result = []
# The input is:
# - a 2-tuple containing:
#   - a list of 2-tuples with (database field) values
#   - length of the list ("number of rows returned")
# Therefore we iterate the first member of the outermost 2-tuple
for item in result[0]:
    # Long version for clarity:
    d = dict()
    d['description'] = item[0]
    d['sum'] = int(item[1])
    list_result.append(d)
    # The short version:
    # list_result.append({'description': item[0], 'sum': int(item[1])})
```

And once you're comfortable with the above, we can shorten all the above to just two lines:

```
# Input data
result = ([('A', 210L), ('B', 1L), ('C', 269L)], 3)
# Reformat to dicts with field names as keys
rows = [{'description': a, 'sum': b} for a,b in result[0]]
```